# How to turn a function r(t) into a quadratic surface equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

[I encountered a question where I have to match some given quadratic surfaces with some given functions r(t). I have the solution below but what I don't get is how they got the equations using the given functions r(t). I would appreciate any help. Thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6wXN.png)

Comment: Please in include all relevant context to your question as text instead of linking to a picture of your problem. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, not to mention inconveniencing people that you’re asking for help by making them chase links to understand your question. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\langle r(t) \rangle = \langle x(t),y(t),z(t) \rangle$

For example, looking at C, we have that $x(t) = 2cos(t), y(t)=3sin(t),z(t)=3-4cos(t)-9sin(t)$

You can observe that $z(t) = 3-2x(t)-3y(t)$ and therefore you can conclude that this is the same as $z=3-2x-3y \to 2x+3y+z=3$ which is a plane.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to *eliminate $t$* to obtain a relation between $(x,y,z)$ which represents a surface. Your eliminations is correct. The curves

A: Spiral on a sphere of unit radius

D: A helix creeping on an elliptic cylinder

E: The generator on a unit radius cylinder